# Having issue with initialize class typed List<T> and private set property in c#

Tags: c#, list, asp.net-core

As I new to asp.net core and `C#`, I don't know how to create object for this generic list type. I have a class with private set properties.

```
[DataContract]    
public class SendResponse: List<SendResponse>{
public SendResponse(string messageId, string recipient)
        {
            MessageId = messageId;
            Recipient = recipient;
        }
 [DataMember]
        public string MessageId { get; private set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Recipient { get; private set; }
}
```

I tried to set the values but it throws object null reference issue

```
           SendResponse sendResponses = null;

            foreach ( var result in results)
            {
                sendResponses.Add(new SendResponse(result.MessageId, result.To));
            }
```

Could you please anyone help me in this?

Comment: what is results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `public class sendResponse: List<Sendresponse>`

Inheriting from `List<T>` is very rarely a good idea.

You probably just want to use a regular list:

```
[DataContract]    
public class SendResponse{
   public SendResponse(string messageId, string recipient)
   {
     MessageId = messageId;
     Recipient = recipient;
   }
   [DataMember]
   public string MessageId { get; private set; }
   [DataMember]
   public string Recipient { get; private set; }
}
```

```
var sendResponses = new List<SendResponse>();

foreach ( var result in results)
{
    sendResponses.Add(new SendResponse(result.MessageId, result.To));
 }
```

Most serialization libraries should handle simple collection types like `T[]` and `List<T>` just fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<SendResponse> sendResponses = new List<SendResponse>();
```